# POST запрос и Response.Locatio C#

Tags: c#, post, get, xnet, site

Здравствуйте, у меня вот такая проблемка.
Я отправляю запрос на авторизацию:

```
request.Post("http://installcube.com/acp/ru/startup/login/", "login=маил&password=пароль").ToString();
```

Далее проверяю прошла ли авторизация:

```
 if (request.Response.Location == "https://installcube.com/acp/ru/dashboard")
```

Но в ответ от сервера я получаю:

```
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
```

Как мне это исправить? Или проверить авторизацию по другому? P.S Куки на сайте нету, только ID сессии.
Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Ну, если вам говорят Moved Permanently, может быть, стоит стучаться на другой адрес? (И да, зачем вам `ToString`?)

Comment: Больше некуда стучать, а ошибка из за Location как я понял.
У меня используется string input = и тут тот Post запрос.

Comment: А, вы ж отправляете Post? Ну так вам редирект и приходит, всё правильно. Вроде где-то можно было флаг поставить `FollowRedirects`, чтобы оно за вас запросило то, что нужно.

Comment: (И да, какого у вас типа request?)

Comment: Наверное, это вам нужно: [`AllowAutoRedirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: HttpRequest
Использую xNet

Comment: Он есть, я уже включал и выключал его, толку ноль.

Comment: А, вы бы про это сказали в вопросе. Я искал в стоковом `HttpWebRequest`. А какой status code приходит?

Comment: request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.Cookies = new CookieDictionary();
request.Referer = "http://installcube.com/";
request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.RandomUserAgent();

                string input = request.Post("http://installcube.com/acp/ru/startup/login/", "login=маил&password=Пароль").ToString();
                if (request.Response.Location == "/acp/ru/dashboard")
                {
                    return "Хорошо";
                }
    else
    {
     return "Плохо";
    }

Comment: Как то плохо код тут выглядит, сейчас скрином кину.

Comment: Аааа! Только не скрин! Редактируйте вопрос, кидайте код туда.

Comment: http://vk.cc/4XjMOC

Comment: Код всё равно будет в полоску.

Comment: @user199587 не кидайте код в *комментарии*, отредактируйте *сам вопрос*!